# How can one know if a paper award decision was made with the award committee not having access to the author names?

Tags: publications, awards

How can one know if a paper award decision was made with the award committee not having access to the author names?

I am mostly interested in machine learning / natural language processing paper awards.

Comment: Ask a committee member over a beer?

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks, it doesn't seem to scale well (I am interested to know for many different awards, and often I'm not at the conference where awards were given).

Comment: That depends on how much you like beer!

Comment: This question is only about a single-blinded review, as it's only asking if the reviewers know the submitters. The other blind can be easier to determine - if you know who's on the award committee, it's not double-blinded (but could be single-blinded).

Comment: @NuclearWang Thanks, good point, question edited.

Comment: At least two of the conferences that I attend decide on the paper awards right before the conference starts, so all the accepted papers (and authors) are known.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by "paper awards"? Are they prizes written on paper as opposed to a statuette or plaque?

Comment: @St.Inkbug awards given to scientific papers.

Comment: Oh, I see! My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases the award committee or sponsoring organization may describe its procedures on its official website.  Otherwise, you can write to the award committee chair and ask.

I don't think there's any more general way to know.  In particular, I doubt that there is any central place where you can find this information for many different awards.  (It would be a pain for someone to collect it and keep it up to date.)